# Question about Intermediate Step in a Proof of the Gauss-Lucas Theorem

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I'm a self-studier and this is my first post to the Math Stacks. I'm working on a proof of the [Gauss-Lucas Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) and have been stuck on a particular intermediate step for a while. If anyone could provide me with a hint as to how to make this deduction, I'd be extremely grateful!

If Im($a_i)>0$ for all $i \in \{1,2,...,k\}$ and if $\frac{1}{b-a_1}+\frac{1}{b-a_2}+...+\frac{1}{b-a_k}=0$, then how could we deduce that Im$(b)>0$?

I've tried multiplying through by $(b-a_1)(b-a_2)...(b-a_k)$, but that doesn't seem to result in a helpful statement. I feel that there is some simple insight that I'm failing to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Apply $\text{Im}$ to both sides of the equation and use $$\text{Im}\left(\frac{1}{b-a_i}\right) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{\overline{b-a_i}}{|b-a_i|^2}\right) = \frac{1}{|b-a_i|^2}\text{Im}\left(a_i-b\right) = \frac{1}{|b-a_i|^2}\left[\text{Im}(a_i)-\text{Im}(b)\right] $$
Given that $\text{Im}(a_i)>0$ for all $i$, this can only sum to $0$ if $\text{Im}(b)>0$.

Comment: Thank you Andreas! I think the key idea I should take away from this is that division by a nonzero complex number can be transformed into multiplication by a different complex number, and the latter form is much easier to work with.